# Proving unitarily equivalence using induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, unitary-matrices

Problem: A matrix B ∈ Mn,n(C) is said to be unitarily equivalent to A ∈ Mn,n(C) if there exists a unitary matrix U ∈ Mn,n(C) such that B= U†AU.
Show that every matrix A ∈ Mn,n(C) is unitarily equivalent to a triangular matrix.

Hint:This is obvious for 1×1 matrices.  Use this as induction hypothesis (A ∈ Mn,n(C)) and prove the statement for A ∈ Mn+1,n+1(C) by induction over n.  You can use that the product of two unitary matrices U,Q ∈ Mn,n(C) is a unitary matrix without having to prove it.

My attempt:
Let's prove this using induction.
Base case: As given in the hint, this is obvious for 1x1 matrices.
Induction hypothesis: There exists positive integer n such that nxn matrix A is unitarily equivalent to a triangular matrix.
Step case: Let A be an n+1 x n+1 matrix. ...

But I have no idea how to do the step case. Using induction over dimension confuses me, since n+1 x n+1 matrices are off course larger than nxn matrices.

Any help, whether it are hints or full answers, are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen inductive proofs of spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices? You find the eigenvector (which always exists, since characteristic polynomial has a root in $\mathbb{C}$), then look at orthogonal complement to the eigenvector, prove it's invariant and induct.

Here it's similar: find an eigenvector, make a basis using this eigenvector and a basis of its orthocomplement. Now see that in this basis your matrix has zeroes down the first column, then induct.

If you get stuck, google "Schur decomposition".